# Why can't we post LMGTFY links in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I just posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407055/796103) answer and got a comment from the author which deserves being replied to with a *let me google that for you* link.

Why can't we post those as comments? I get the following error message:

> Comments cannot contain that content.

---

**Edit:** just noticed I can't even post them in a question body. Why is that?

---

**Another Edit:** Can you explain why I'm getting downvoted? Because I think it would've been correct to use such a link? I was asking **why** and don't think the question deserves downvotes?

Comment: Because they're rude. You could indeed have provided reference links in your answer. As it is, it's quite minimal.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Don't you think it's rude from the author instead to not even have a closer look at what I suggested?

Comment: Rude, less, but the question is indeed poor to begin with (which is another matter entirely). If you still choose to answer it, then don't only perform lip service, or don't be surprised if the questioner won't do any research effort.

Comment: cfr [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links), although I totally agree people not even taking time to proper search sometimes deserve people being rude with them... but instead of that kind of answer/comment, just ignore, downvote, ...

Comment: @Bartdude, if the questioner did not take the time to research, then the right thing to do is to downvote and/or close the question, not answer it then say you have a right to be rude to the questioner.

Comment: IMO: posting links to LMGTFY is fighting fire with fire - it can only get worse from there.

Comment: You can do the same google search on two different computers and see different results which should help show why not everyone finds things easily with google.

Comment: @JoeW: True, but most of the times it's simply a case of looking for the wrong key words.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because l m g t f y.com/?q=Why+can%27t+I+use+lmgtfy+links+on+stackoverflow%3F

Comment: @Cerbrus most of the time it's simply a case copy/pasting the title, as-is, into the Google search box:(

Comment: @MartinJames: exactly. And prople still fail to do that.

Answer (score 11):

It'd be inappropriate if my answer simply contained (I had to shorten it, because of the ban):

http://bfy.tw/o1v

---

The reason it's not allowed is because it is rude. It provides no context to your comment other than pointing someone at the door and telling them to walk through it.

Comment: I should add that if you repeatedly use link shorteners to work around the ban on LMGTFY links, moderators might have a conversation with you about that. [I wish we'd just blacklist those, too.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257940/19679)

Comment: @BradLarson: that's good to know! The shortener in these 2 answers is hosted by lmgtfy, maybe it's a good idea to add at least that domain to the lmgtfy ban.

Comment: Giving someone a google link is pointing them at the door and telling them to walk through it. Giving them an lmgtfy link goes beyond that ... it's intended to mock. From the comments under Cerbrus's answer, it's apparent that some people lack the intellectual honesty to admit that.

Comment: @JimBalter "it's intended to mock." I don't think that this is true for everyone.  I *do* think that, regardless of intention, some people are not amused by being directed to a lmgtfy link.  It is possible that some people do not realize that they are hurting peoples' feelings.  To insinuate that they are *intending* to hurt people's feelings is a serious accusation and requires evidence.

Comment: "a serious accusation and requires evidence" -- LOL. Let's see Scott provide evidence for every statement he makes in a comment online.

Answer (score 8):

Because lmgtfy links are rude.

Lead by example, explain that the user could better have searched if you *have* to, with some example search phrases:

> Possible duplicate of <link>. Try searching for *"Some keywords"*, if you have any further issues with this subject.

[Here are plenty of results explaining why lmgtfy links are considered rude](http://bfy.tw/o1e).

Even lmgtfy's "about" considers the recipients of those links to be bothers:

> LMGTFY is for all those people who find it more convenient to bother you with their question rather than google it for themselves.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what LMGTFY does? It shows them what search terms they could use. And frankly, googling for a class I suggested him to use seems quite obvious, doesn't it?

Comment: Instead of lmgtfy, How about linking to a google search? Or better yet, some decent results? lmgtfy just sends a message that the user is "dumb" enough not to know how to google... _"Oh, it looks like you don't know how to perform one of the most basic internet actions. let me link you to a animation that **slowly** shows you how to search."_

Comment: @Cerbrus > Sometimes, people are dumb/lazy enough not to do it indeed... but indeed it's much better to give those people the time they deserve and just move on to a more interresting question...

Comment: I don't see how linking a google search is less rude. It also shows them that they are "dumb" enough not to know how to google.

Comment: Also do you *really* think "Try searching for 'UIAlertController', if you have any further issues with this subject." is any helpful regarding the fact that all I did was recommend him to use this very class?

Comment: Frankly, if you don't see the difference between a lmgtfy link, and some found results with a suggestion what to look for next time, I can't help you.

Comment: @Christian, have you clicked on a LMGTFY link? There is a patronizing aspect (the cursor moving by itself and the narration that looks targeted to a mentally-impaired teenager) that is far more offensive than posting a simple link.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But the message is the same: You should have googled it yourself. It just puts more emphasis on one simple fact: they should learn to do a simple search before asking others to do so.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr: We get it, you don't think lmgtfy is rude. We disagree. I don't think there's any point in continuing this discussion, for any of us.

Comment: @Christian, you may consider the message to be the same and only its expression to be different, yes. But the expression does matter. I'm sure you appreciate us discussing the matter with you with actual words instead of slapping you in the face while doing it or posting a LMGTFY link to the duplicate, for instance :)

Comment: @Cerbrus If you think it's rude, then why did you post one yourself?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr: That's called "Humor", I suppose.

Comment: @Cerbrus Kay I get it. If I ask why I get downvoted. If you do it its humor and you get upvoted.

Comment: You ask _why_ you can't use those links. This implies you want to use those links. People disagree with that, so downvote your post. My answer explains _why not_ to use such links, _and_ offers an illustration as to why it's considered rude. That's completely different. If all I posted was that link, I'm sure i'd have gotten just as many downvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus In this very case, yes, I thought it was appropriate. But my question shouldn't be downvoted for that. Downvoted cuz duplicate, yes, fine. But downvoting for something entirely different than the subject of my question is like going to my profile and downvoting everything I ever posted just because you don't like my attitude / me as a person.

Comment: Voting's different on meta, Christian. Disagreeing with a post is a valid vote reason on meta.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry, but I don't see how you can disagree with a question. I did not say 'Hey I want to post LMGTFY links'. I asked **why**, with a little addition on how I found out I could not.

Comment: The votes do not affect your repu at StackOverflow - so it is not relevant if the question is down- or upvoted. This does only reflect the users opinions.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr A question titled like yours is obviously seeking to have  these links re-enabled, and people either disagree with that, or they don't appreciate such an obvious question being asked. Don't take voting personally, especially on Meta where it doesn't affect your reputation. Just take it as a sign that the community disagrees with you. Swallow that, and move on.

Comment: There is little chance of such posters on here being "dumb" enough not to know how to Google.  It's more a case of street-smarts: "Why waste my time looking through the Google results, selecting good ones and then writing my own, unique homework answer?  I copy a line from my assignment onto SO and the Google-drones do most of the work for me whilke I'm down the bar. OK, it's not really fair on them, but who gives any fucks for naive nerds with the IQ of a mushroom?"

Comment: COMPLETELY DISAGREE THAT IT'S RUDE! Rude is when you make an answer fun and interesting (because so much in programming is boring and mundane) and some ahole moderator with a grudge comes and changes your answer just to be an a$$. LMGTFY links are not rude, but legit. 99.9% of the time, if you're receiving such link, it's because you're being to lazy to do a very simple action. Of course, I also disagree with the statement "there are no stupid questions." Yes. Yes there are stupid questions.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: your definition of “rude” seems to conflic with that of SO. Editing off-topic content out of answers isn’t rude.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is when it's simply a personal grudge, and when it removes, as aforementioned, the elements of fun. sorry, but one thing i simply dont agree with on this sight is all the "stiffness". I've been here for years and seems like it wasn't near as stiff several years ago as it has become. also as aforementioned, the jerk i refer to only does it out of personal grudge from an argument we had 2 years ago and he never got over.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: So flag that. That one user you seem to have bad blood with is in no way representative of SO.

Comment: LMGTFY links are considered rude? Well, sometimes actually appropriate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369358/how-does-electromagnetic-interference-affect-power-consumption?noredirect=1#comment891640_369358

Comment: @user9214072: There isn't a"LMGTFY" link in there...

Comment: @Cerbrus Because it was blocked by the comment system. But I mean that the person, who asks what a PMR446 device is, which is self-evident to me, should search.

Comment: Yes, they should search. but that doesn't mean "LMGTFY" isn't rude.

Comment: It's funny how some people here claim that LMGTFY isn't rude, and as part of their explanation state that some people really are so stupid and lazy that they deserve an LMGTFY answer.