# Why are link shorteners useful for spammers?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, external-links

This question is related to: [Blacklist the use of common link shorteners in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313621/4928642).

Why are shortened links more useful for spammers than the usual ones?
Spammers can post any link, so why do we pay special attention if it is shortened?

If the post is link-only or has a bad quality, I think, links have to be checked during the review phase regardless of whether they are shortened. If the post is high-quality but the link points to spam - it's a very strange case, I do not think it happens often.

So I do not see the problem with shortened links except [what I wrote here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313622/4928642). What did I miss?

Comment: Where does `http://somephishingsite.nasty` take you? Now how about `http://link.ly/xyz`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe now I want a domain in that .nasty TLD.

Comment: Surely you can see that not being able to see at all what url you are going to end up navigating to is phishy?

Comment: @Gimby, do you really think, that any phising site can be guessed by url?

Comment: Not everyone, but some, yes. So why make their lives easier?

Comment: @Qwertiy to bad you only react to the pun, and not to the actual point; you don't see where you'll be directed to. To me that's the same thing as offering code as a self-extracting executable. A very unnecessary security risk.

Comment: I would say the large majority of phishing sites can be identified by their url. From what I've read, I don't think that's really what we care about preventing by disallowing link shorteners, we're trying to stop people using them too obfuscate known bad urls for products they spam.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not so much about why these are useful to spammers, but why they are a problem for us. Obfuscated links cannot be searched by moderators or normal users, so we can't find other instances of spam easily or determine patterns among spammers once a single spam post has been identified. They force reviewers and moderators to take a risk in verifying the destination address.

I'll give you one example that prompted my feature request. There is a persistent spam group that has been dumping links to a product called SQLYog on the site for years. They have created dozens of accounts to do this. For years, their spam [linked back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19831165/19679) to [their website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23729637/19679), so as soon as one was detected, we could run a URL search and find the others that terrible reviewers approved (thankfully, the review audits have reduced the frequency at which their spam is being approved). They recognized this, and started obfuscating [some of their links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289446/19679). Now they [only post obfuscated links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506932/19679). This means that we cannot search for their product URLs directly anymore. Some reviewers are still approving their spam.

Outside of spam, another case is discussed in my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257940/19679). A user trolled the site by injecting porn site links using shortened URLs in edits like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4839936) that reviewers approved. Had the reviewers seen the target URL in the markdown, they probably would not have.

I recognize that motivated trolls will still find a way to hide their links, but we've found most spammers are pretty lazy. If we can make it just a little harder for them to take advantage of the community, I think it will help us all out.

Comment: The porn example is indeed a very relevant case outside of security issues or spam; you can't know what is being linked to is safe for work, or safe for kids.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that SQLYog is spamming the site, I've always thought about buying a product or 2 of theirs but I will be sure to pass now.