# Odd audit question?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I've run into some audit decisions I've questioned before, but here's one I simply do NOT understand:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10784002

The reason given for removing this is "It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful."

I see absolutely nothing of the sort. It's an answer, it's polite. Or am I off-base?

Comment: Probably a spammer spamming links to that tool.

Comment: How these people spam SO is the subject of [Brad's answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313689/17034).  You pass these kind of audits by paying attention and note that the post is not actually present in the Q+A.  Product recommendations are your first cue that there is something fishy going on.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I did notice it was not in the "full page" - but that didn't ring the alarm bells soon enough that I was dealing with an audit. And I'm actually still not clear that this was recognizable as "spam". The information preceding the link seemed quite reasonable.

Comment: @CindyMeister that's the point.  Spammers have gotten more sophisticated.  You should follow Hans' advice and be extra careful on recommendation questions.  For example, you should view the question in a new tab and close it.  If the answer doesn't appear, then it's an audit that expects a delete vote.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes, I did do that. But in my book that's "cheating" as far as the point of the audit goes. The point of the audit would be that I recognize this as spam WITHOUT the clue - it could be real, not an audit. The link target, itself, does not seem harmful. From that I conclude that this tool and those who promote it are "known" to a certain circle of reviewers (I'm familiar with a few of those, myself, from "my" MSDN forums). I'm not sure it's reasonable, however, to assume that everyone working the queues can be expected to recognize this.

Comment: @CindyMeister it's not "cheating" because due diligence for recommendation questions (even just for answers in the VLQ reviews) is to try to _close the off-topic question_.  You're already there on the Q&A, so you might as well check the status of the answer too.  The only clue you need is that it's a recommendation (or otherwise off-topic/broad) question.

Comment: [Why are link shorteners useful for spammers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313685/why-are-link-shorteners-useful-for-spammers) explicitly mentions SPAM by those ... people pointing to their site.

Comment: Yeah, my brain is starting to sort it out... Thanks to all for their informative links and patience!